# Nuxt JS page content flicker when changing pages

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt JS v2.4.5 with Bootstrap Vue, I have a fixed header and a page footer that are located inside of my default.vue file.

When I scroll to the bottom of a page and click a link in the footer, using the following, it takes me to the top of the new page as expected, however the content appears to occasionally flicker for a few ms before loading the content, I'm using:

```
router: {
    scrollBehavior: function (to, from, savedPosition) {
      return { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }
  }
```

This appears to be a common problem in Nuxt JS as it's of course not technically a page refresh, how could I go about fixing this?

Many Thanks.